# How to refresh ListeView adapter in fragment from another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, adapter

In My app I have a `Fragment` called `DownloadsFragment` that shows Videos in a specified path in a ListView, using a `Custom Adapter` class extending a BaseAdapter.

In getView() method of my `Adapter`, I call CardItems.xml that contain a button that shows a `DeleteActivity` to delete Video from path.

when the `downloadFragment` start I press the delete button, the `DeleteActivity` start I delete the item from it the activity finished and when I back to DownloadsFragment and I scroll the listview I get an error:

> ArrayOutOfBoundIndex

(number of the deleted video ) and the app crash, my question is how to refresh listview from the delete activity after it will finish and back to Downloads Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something quite similar but I'm no sure how clean is this:

In `DownloadsFragment` create a global `Fragment`:

```
public static Fragment myFragment;
```

And in `onCreate` of that `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myFragment = this;
}
```

Then in your `Activity` or wherever you want yo refresh `DownloadsFragment`, do something like this:

```
Fragment frg = DownloadsFragment.myFragment;
  if (frg != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frg).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(frg).commitAllowingStateLoss();
 }
```

**Update**

Or create a method in your `Fragment`:

```
public void refreshFragment() {
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
 //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And wherever you want yo refresh that `Fragment`, do something like this:

```
DownloadsFragment f = (DownloadsFragment) DownloadsFragment.myFragment;
f.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your Fragment Tag");
   if (f!= null) {
      f.refreshFragment();
}
```

Or make that method static and call:*(I'm not sure if this will work. you have to test it yourself)*

```
DownloadsFragment.refreshFragment();
```

Comment: glad to hear it. and don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem.

Comment: works for me, almost forgot to assign the fragment in `onCreate()`